# Question in Proof of Fundamental theorem of Algebra using Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

While self studying Galois theory from Thomas Hungerford. I have questions in the proof of Fundamental theorem of Algebra(Pg 266) .

Adding image ->[image]

> i have questions in 2 line of 2 nd paragraph of proof . Please note that ||.5.7 is Sylow 1 st Theorem. 
>   1.Why H must have odd index? 
>   2.Why fixed field E has odd dimension?

Comment: 1. Definition of a 2-Sylow; 2. The dimension of $E$ is by Galois theory the index of $H$.

Comment: @Mindlack can you please prove 2 !!

Comment: $[Aut(F):H]=[Gal(F/\mathbb{R}):Gal(F/E)]=\frac{|Gal(F/\mathbb{R})|}{|Gal(F/E)|}=\frac{[F:\mathbb{R}]}{[F:E]}=[E:\mathbb{R}]$.

Comment: @Mindlack I am asking my question as a seperate question.  This question is clear to me. Thanks!!